# Django javascript fetch post method problem

Tags: javascript, django

I have problem with javascript fetch post method
Django get my request as key not key => value

Javascript

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}, header) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(data)
    let headers = header;
    const response = await fetch(url, { method: 'POST', credentials: 'include', headers, body});
    return await response.json();
}
share.onclick = () => {
    titul = title.value;
    cont = content.value;
    postData('createPost/', {
        title: titul,
        content: cont,
    },{
      'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'X-CSRFToken' : csrftoken,
      "Accept": "application/json",
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    })
};
```

views.py

```
def js_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return JsonResponse({'status' : 'OK'})
        return JsonResponse({'status' : 'Maybe', 'request' : request.POST})
    return JsonResponse({'status' : 'BAD'})
```

Chrome Console

*

status: "Maybe"

request: {"title":"scaknsakc","content":"asckcksac"}: ""           //// key : ' '

*

Comment: 1. What you're sending is JSON, so the commented out `Content-Type` header setting `application/json` was correct, you should put it back. 2. It's not the problem, but you should be checking `ok` before calling `response.json()`; more [on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: I tried it but i get empty request

Comment: That's how you send JSON in the post body, so the problem is presumably Django-side. (I don't know Django at all, but you'll presumably have to tell it in advance that it's dealing with a JSON post body rather than the usual URI-encoded one.)

Comment: try printing request.body in django if it prints proper data then use json.loads and pass to forms

Comment: i try bu t i get error
Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Comment: Pavan Kumar T S Thanks json.load is working